# What does (heated) mean in a chemical equation?

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium, heat

I'm supposed to balance the following equation:

$$\text{Potassium chlorate (heated)} \rightarrow \text{Potassium chloride + Oxygen}$$

But I don't understand what is meant by the label "heated" in front of the first element. Do I ignore it, or am I supposed to add another element to the reactants of the equation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of balancing the equation, the fact that heat must be supplied can be ignored.  It is just providing information about the conditions necessary to run the reaction.

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with a combustion reaction?

Comment: Usually it just means to supply thermal heat to a solution or a solid.  For example, heat the flask containing a solution of potassium chlorate.  A more detailed experimental procedure would specify how much heat and for how long (e.g. dissolve the potassium chlorate in water and then heat to reflux for 1 hour).

Comment: Energy the forgotten reactant in chemistry! Did not some famous scientist establish that mass-energy is what is conserved.  For this reaction to happen smoothly a catalyst, usually MnO2, is advisable. BTW boiling in water would be a different reaction if it happened, either oxidation of water or disproportionation of the Chlorate ion.